# (PHP) No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Tags: php, mysql, database, connection

I'm creating a PHP application and have a local test enviroment on both my laptop and desktop.

EDIT: [Generated logs in a pastebin](https://pastebin.com/gaNjbZvc).

I am using the WPN-XM Serverstack.

Everything worked fine beforehand, but now on my laptop, when I try to do anything that requires a connection with the database, it throws this error.

> No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it

Did some research and found out that it could be a problem with my firewall, turned it off, same result.

Read elsewhere that this is not an issue with my code, this makes sense since everything works on my desktop.

Things I've tried so far:

- Restarted the webserver
- Restarted the laptop
- Turned off the firewall
- Login to phpMyAdmin (Error: Cannot log in to the MySQL server)
- Changed the port of the webserver to 8080

Any idea what might be causing this error?

For completeness, altough the problem is more than likely not in the code, here' s the connection file.

```
$name = "root";
$pass = "";
$db = "myDB";
$host = "localhost";

$connect = mysqli_connect($host, $name, $pass, $db);

if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Could not connect to the mysql database. Error: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}
```

Comment: Are you 100% sure your MySQL server is up and running?

Comment: try to change the port the local server is using (I assume it's set to 80 by default: http://127.0.0.1:80)

Comment: I don't know if you're familiar with WPN-XM. It comes with a batch file that starts all the services. So I'm 99% sure that it's actually running. I do have some logs that I will attach in the post now.

Comment: @lovelace Changed it to 8080, didn't work, same result.

Comment: If you put `die('Hello World');` in the top of your PHP file, do you see that? If it is your connection to MySQL that fails, then changing the port of the web server won't help. Those or two totally different services. Please make sure that the MySQL service is started (100%). Even if a script starts it, applications can crash and shutdown.

Comment: @MagnusEriksson Yes, I see a blank page with just `Hello World`.

Comment: Then the web server works as expected, so no reason to change those ports.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled for hours with exactly the same problem!
I tried my first time to start a mysql server and connect it with php code, learning it from reading raghwendras blogpost. I copyed his code from github and did everything he told me to in the description but still got the error.
I am using XAMPP for hosting the localserver and running mysql.

I solved the problem by reading about all the parameters that $myqli_connect() has, and the solution was to add the **portnumber** in the $mysqli_connect like this:

```
$mysqli_connect("localhost", "username", "password", "yourDbName", PORTNUMBER)
```

Now when I log onto `phpmyadmin` the tables will update with the information that I pass into the  after submiting.